# Localization in javascript via IHttpHandlers

Tags: asp.net, json, globalization, resx, ihttphandler

What's the best way to acces .resx files in a Http Handler in ASP.NET?

I need to access them in javascript. My goal is to serialize them in JSON via a IHttpHandler. The problem is that I simply can't figure out which .resx I should load according to request language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use GetGlobaResourceObject or GetLocalResourceObject as here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx

Comment: I just found out that these lines work 

 HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("/path/of/page.aspx", "resourceKey");
 HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("fileInApp_GlobalResources", "resourceKey")

But how can I get all resources available from these resx files?

Comment: this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file