# How can i count Resources in a folder

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, directory

I Have several images set as **Resources** in my project.
now i want to store in a variable the amount of images i have in that folder.

How can i achive this?
I Am building a WPF Application.
When i try and use Pack URL like this :

```
 string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Output/", "*.jpg");
```

i get an error that The given path's format is not supported.

**Notes:**

- The resources are not specified in some file, they are just set as Resources on it's **Build Action**.
- I only need **some** of the images in the assembly. They are within a specific folder

**Strings i tried:**

- pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Output/
- YearBook;component/Resources/Images/Output/

Comment: Please don't put things like "in C#" or "[WPF]" in your title.  This is what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as normal C# code (using `Directory.GetFile()`) and wrap it into a T4 Template.

You can't count the resources, so you have to count the files the will be used as resources. 
Here a first shot:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#
    var directory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.Host.TemplateFile), "Resources");
    var folderCounter = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.*").Length;
#>

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyFilesCounter
    {
        public static int FilesInFolder = <#= folderCounter #>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but how would i do that? i don't know what uri to use

Comment: But this is not from Resources it's from D:\. i need to deploy this to computers and need images saved in the assembly.

Comment: You can't count the resources, so you have to count the files the will be used as resources. I updated my answer that you get the folder where the T4 file resides. From there you can then adapt the path to the place you like.

Comment: I seem to be missing some knowledge, never used a template before. i've tried writing the <#= folderCountrt #> in the page i need but it dosen't recognize the <> tags

Comment: Change the file extension of the file in your project to `.tt`, read [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) and install [this Visual Studio Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/40a887aa-f3be-40ec-a85d-37044b239591).

Comment: Yep this worked, i didn't need to install the extention because i'm using Visual Studio 2010 i guess, Thank you very much for your help kind sir :)

Comment: @eric.itzhak: You don't need the extension to let it work in Visual Studio. But the extension gives you syntax highlighting and intellisense in your .tt files.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
ResourceSet resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
{
    string resourceName = entry.Key; //if you need all this, but who knows.
    object resource = entry.Value;

    if ((resource.GetType() == typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap) || resource.GetType() == typeof(System.Drawing.Icon)) && 
         resourceName == "someString")
    {
        i++;
    }    
}

MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

Redirect your votes to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2041049/661933) :)

Comment: But this will count all my resource images, but i want to count only some. By the way i didn't mention i'm using WPF so i changed Bitmap to BitmapImage and it didn't count no items.

Comment: How do we know which images should be counted and which shouldn't be. Please mention your requirement clearly in the question. Give more if clauses before you increment the variable `i` in the code. I'll edit it

Comment: I have used this successfully to get the number of image items in my resources using this code. Are you sure you have got image files added as resx files?

Comment: no their not in resx files ( i've edited the question), their just images with build action set to Resources. i am using them in other parts of code and their working perfectly, so i know their in there

Comment: If they are not resx files, I think you are accessing from other parts by specifying the physical path. In that case give the proper path. I am not very competent in WPF aspects for that matter.