# How to get names of resource file in list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resx

Asp.net Mvc application.
In project there is a resource.resx file, where there are information.
From resource file I want to get the list of names.
Everybody can me help?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this by iterating through the resources through the  `ResourceManager.GetResourceManagerSet()` method.

For more info see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file) ...

Comment: @Gurgen Hovsepyan please don't forget to accept if it's answred your question?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath.Replace("bin\\\Debug", "Resources"));
           foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
               comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```