# Looping through a set of image resources (.resx)

Tags: c#, resources, resx

I've got a 3 sets of 9 images in seperate .resx files, and I'm trying to figure out how to loop a single set into 9 static picture boxes.

[Loop through all the resources in a .resx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file)

I've looked through some of the solutions in the above link, like using `ResXResourceReader`, but it comes up with a parsing error when I use the `GetEnumerator` method.

When I use the `ResourceSet resourceSet = MyResourceClass.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);` line, there's no definition for the `ResourceManager` within the `Form` class, or a `GetResourceSet` method when I create my own `ResourceManager`.

There is actually a method called `CreateFileBasedResourceManager` which I've dabbled in, but truth be told I don't understand the parameters it needs too well aside from the directory.

I've also looked at some of the solutions involving assemblies and retrieving the executing image assembly at runtime, but I think that's a little out of my depth at the moment.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the first two methods or maybe something entirely different?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at MSDN, you should be able to iterate the values from a RESX file like so:

```
string resxFile = @".\CarResources.resx";


// Get resources from .resx file.
  using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile))
  {
     // Retrieve the image.
     Object image =  resxSet.GetObject("NAMEOFFILE", true);
  }
```

If you wanted to iterate all objects in the RESX file, you could do something like this:

```
using (ResXResourceReader resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(resxFile))
  {
     foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resxReader) {
        // entry.Key is the name of the file
        // entry.Value is the actual object...add it to the list of images you were looking to keep track of
     } 
  }
```

More can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx).

Comment: I keep coming up with a parsing error when it looks at the first image in the resx file I have it look at.

Comment: string resxFile = @"//File path ending in Theme1Images.resx";
                using (ResXResourceReader resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(resxFile))
                {foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resxReader)
                    {string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
                        object resource = entry.Value;
                        MessageBox.Show("message");} }


This is all in a try-catch:
ArgumentException was unhandled
ResX file Could not find a part of the path '//FilePath\bin\resources\1336578195503.jpg'. Line 123, position 5. cannot be parsed.

Comment: @Jamz And that file exists in the \bin\resources folder?

Answer (score 2):

I known that this is a old question, but today I got the same problem, and solve setting the BasePath property, like this:

```
oResReader = new ResXResourceReader(strInputFile);
oResReader.BasePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(strInputFile);
```

I found this solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/876b0194-a6cf-4d66-a7c2-491847c9006c/resource-file-loading-fails-with-resxresourcereader)