# Resources with .Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, resources, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got an MVC application which does use some custom routing:

```
{Customer}/{Entity}/{Action}
```

The `{Customer}` route variable could be understood like the localization variable. I'd like to change the labels on the views according to the value in `{Customer}`. This means for `Customer1`, `Field1` is labeled `Username` and for `Customer2`, `Field1` is named `LoginName`. (example doesn't make sense, but should show the requirement).

How can I achieve the desired result? I started with creating two resource-files `Labels.Customer1.resx` and `Labels.Customer2.resx` but don't know how to enable these in the view.

By the way, I'm NOT using the razor-engine.

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking to extract what the route variable named `{Customer}` is? `/foo/bar/baz` get's `foo`? `/a/b/c` get's `a`?

Comment: Normally resource files are based on languages? Setting the Thread.CurrentUICulture to the culture specified in the resx would use that cultureinformation.

Comment: no, I'm extracting the {Customer} at several points of the application, that's not the point. I'm wondering how to use resource-files for the problem which is not actually regarding the currentUICulture...

Answer (score 1):

The links I am adding below show how to use resources files and how to use the values inside them to replace the label's values in order to change a different value according tho the resource file you have chosen.

According to this you can create a property where you can set the current resource file.
Once you have set the current resource file you can call the values for each label from there

http://www.4microsoftsolutions.com/post/AspNet-Globalization-and-Localization-using-Local-Resource-files-and-Global-Resource-files-.aspx

[Loop through all the resources in a .resx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file)

Comment: not that easy to implement. looks like it's quite impossible the way I want this. My solution: I am going to create a dedicated class just for providing the view with strings, dynamically loaded from xml-files.