# Loading in multilingual terms from RESX file dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, resources, multilingual

My project requires me to have a multilingual feature, so using `Global.resx` I have a list of English terms and in `Global.fr.resx` I have a list of French terms. This works perfectly. I can call in the term I require by using @Resources.Global. Whatever.

However, I now need to display these terms dynamically from the RESX file in a `foreach`, from values gathered from the entity framework. Any idea?

Bit more info:

The code is very simple, I'm still learning C#, I'm working in the View, so literally I have @Resources.Global.Whatever to display static terms and then I have a foreach loop:

`<ul>`

`@foreach (var category in Model.categories)`

`{ <li>@category.categoryName</li> }`

`</ul>`

Where I want @category.categoryName to be called from @Resource.Global too.

Comment: Show your problematic code, it's in a View ? You mean for example using an `Html.DisplayFor` and get value from resx, or what ?

Comment: How is EntityFramework related? What do you want the `foreach` for? Also: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve items from a resource file based on a **dynamic** key name (i.e. something in a variable?). You could create an extension method for this, like so (obviously replacing the namespace to the namespace of your resource file):

```
 public static string Resource(this string name)
 {
     return new ResourceManager(
             "YourApp.Namespace.Resources",
             Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetString(name) ?? name;
 }
```

Then for a `foreach`, you could do this (assuming `yourList` is a list of strings):

```
foreach (string item in yourList)
{
    item = item.Resource();
}
```

Or even just using Linq?

```
List<string> resourceStrings = yourList.Select(s => s.Resource()).ToList();
```