# How to Hold a Collection in a RESX file?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to have a single key in a resx file reference a List, or some other collection?

I noticed [this question asked elsewhere](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97d13805-188f-46af-a5dd-7cab87d0b3d6/resx-file-keycollectionvalues?forum=csharpgeneral), but those who answered didn't seem to understand the question.

In other cases, I see discussion of how to [iterate through keys in a resx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298722/wpf-creating-a-list-or-array-of-items-in-a-resx-file).

I suspect it isn't possible to have a single key which has a collection as a value.  I suspect that iterating the resx file is indeed the only substitute - but I want to know what others have found.

Comment: I suppose you could just serialize the list into one key of the resx file?

Comment: You can store anything you want in a .resx file, binary serialization is used to store non-trivial data.  Getting it into the .resx file is the tricky part.  If the IDE doesn't do it for you, like the various designers do, then it gets to be unpractical.