# Looping through RESX file, items not in order

Tags: c#, resx

I am looping through a resx file, using the method described here in the accepted answer here: [Loop through all the resources in a .resx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file)

But the items are not being read in the order that they are in the resx file which is what I would have expected.
The ordering is not random and is preserved between reads, but is returned:
Line3
Line2
Line1
Line6
Line5
Line4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary/Hashtabels do not preserve order of elements. There also no guarantees that order will be the same between run-time versions, x86/x64/other flavors or even runs of the same binaries (also usually order stays the same).

[ResourceSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The ResourceSet class enumerates over an IResourceReader, loading every name and value, and **storing them in a Hashtable**. A custom IResourceReader can be used.