# Get an array of images from a resx file C#

Tags: c#, arrays, image, resx

I'm having problems getting images from my Properties.Resources into an array. Each image has its own name, but I can't find a way to easily put them into an array without manually typing them all out like so.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap[] imageArray = new System.Drawing.Bitmap[29];
imageArray[0] = Properties.Resources.acorno;
imageArray[1] = Properties.Resources.batterymanD;
imageArray[2] = Properties.Resources.batterymanMicroCell;
```

etc.

Is there an easy way to make an array from my Resources.resx file, without changing the names of the files?

Comment: are you familiar with the `foreach()` method..? you could implement something based on a Collection for example

Comment: I'm not familiar with the foreach() method, is there a link you could direct me to for an understanding of it?

Comment: do a google search as well on Looping thru Resource File C# here is another link that is on StackOverflow that can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file

Comment: not a problem.. let us know if that works for you or worked for you ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ResourceSet to generate the array:

```
var resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
System.Drawing.Bitmap[] imageArray = resourceSet.OfType<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(i => (System.Drawing.Bitmap)i.Value)
    .ToArray();
```