# How can I get key Based on value in resource file using c#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, resx

I want **key** Name based on **value**.
My resource code below

```
<data name="FoodTruck" xml:space="preserve"><value>Food truck</value></data>
```

I have value **Food truck** now I want Key name **FoodTruck**.

I am using Xamarin C#.

Comment: try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2041049/1240523

Comment: @RobVoisey I can't find **ResourceSet** in Xamarin C#

Answer (score 2):

Try it code:

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = typeof(AppResources)
            .GetRuntimeFields()
            .First(m => m.Name == "resourceMan")
            .GetValue(typeof(AppResources)) as System.Resources.ResourceManager;

//or this variant
var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(AppResources));

//CultureInfo culture 
ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false); 
var nameItem = rs.OfType<DictionaryEntry>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == "YourValue"); 
var name = nameItem.Key.ToString();
```

use it in platform specific projects (Xamarin.Droid or Xamarin.iOS)

Example:

in PCL projects:

```
public interface IGetName
{
    string GetName (string value);
}
```

in Android project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AppGetName ))]
namespace YourNamespace 
 ....
 public class AppGetName : IGetName
   {
       public string GetName (string value)
       {
             System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = typeof(AppResources)
                .GetRuntimeFields()
                .First(m => m.Name == "resourceMan")
                .GetValue(typeof(AppResources)) as 
      System.Resources.ResourceManager;



    //CultureInfo culture 
    ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false); 
    var nameItem = rs.OfType<DictionaryEntry>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == "YourValue"); 
    var name = nameItem.Key.ToString();
    return name;
       }
   }
```

using in PCL projects:

```
var getName = DependencyService.Get<IAppGetName>();
var name = getName.GetName("YourValue");
```

Comment: I can't find ResourceSet in Xamarin C#

Comment: Do you use this code in  platform specific project?

Comment: No, It is xamarin.forms PCL project. 
ResourceSet class is not available. and I am not looking for Renderer.

Comment: Unfortunately this code work only in platform specific project. I think you need a rendering.

Comment: Ok, No problem thanks for the help. If you find any solution for without rendering then please let me know. I upvote you for your help :)

Comment: if I use rendering then in which method I need to put above code for iOS render?

Comment: I checked this code for Android. For iOS need check this code. The usage depends on your logic - see my answer I added a simple example of rendering.

Comment: private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
from AppResources.Desinger.cs

Comment: the type and namespace could not be found "AppResources"

Comment: Do you use resx file(in PCL project)? If yes - open YourFile.Designer.cs and find field private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150895/discussion-between-ziyad-godil-and-fetfrumos).