# c# WPF - Resources names in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to get all resource names from properties.resources and fill listbox with them.
Here is code:

```
static string GetNameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    return (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var s = GetNameOf(() => Properties.Resources.Lil);
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

***(with this button and messagebox i try output)***

Here is OK, but the problem is that i must take every resource separately. My idea is to take names foreach resource most inteligent. Maybe is easy but I still learn and I'm still new in codding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through all the resources in a .resx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var properties = typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties(
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
{
    var s = propertyInfo.Name;
    if(s != "ResourceManager" && s != "Culture")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can get names except some name ?

Comment: Use an if-statement as above?

Comment: You are god! :)