# How to access files in dll

Tags: c#, dll

Good time of day. There is a folder with files in the dll project. How to access these files from the dll class, if not to make them resources (so as not to know in advance the number of these files - otherwise you need to use reflection)?[image]

Comment: If you *bake* it into the DLL, then these are resources. If you don't put them there, these files must be loaded like any other through the file system and you must ensure that these files are deployed in conjunction with your library (e.g. set in properties to Content and CopyIfNewer and adopt your installer project).

Comment: @Oliver, that is, if you don't copy files next to the dll every time, then only resources?

Comment: Yes, if you like to inline additional files into an assembly then resources are the way to go.

Comment: And if you like to iterate through all resources available within an assembly at runtime, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2041049/1838048)